# How to iterate over a string to construct nagios_service check as exported resource?

Tags: ruby, erb, puppet, nagios

I wrote a custom fact, which returns a comma separated list of `addr:port`, like this:

```
sb_intl_conn => sbcms-t:22,sbsql05-wvuk-inst5:1434,sborc07-uk-t:1533,..,..,..
```

The number of elements in the string varies from node to node. I need to do a Nagios tcp-port-check on each of them. I think `sb_intl_conn.split(",")` will turn this string into an array and then how can I iterate over it to do something like this?

```
@@nagios_service { "check_stat_${::fqdn}_${addr}_${port}":
    use                 => 'generic-service',
    check_command       => "remote-nrpe-tcp-check!${addr}!${port}",
    service_description => "V2::CON: ${addr} [Palms]",
    display_name        => "Connection check: ${addr}:${port}",
    servicegroups       => 'batch-worker',
    hostgroup_name      => 'batch-job',
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

---

**Update: 1**

I was tying to simulator iamauser's suggestion but not been able to get my head around it yet. This is what I did: in my foo.pp:

```
class test::foo {

    define bar {
        $var1 = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar($name).split(':').first.to_s.chomp %>")
        $var2 = inline_template("<%= scope.lookupvar($name).split(':').last.to_s.chomp %>")
        notify {"${var1}_${var2}": }
    }
}
```

and then in my node.pp:

```
$ifs = ['abc.com:80','xyz.co.uk:1512']
test::foo::bar {$ifs:}
```

which throws in these error on the node:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse inline template: Could not find value for 'abc' in 65 at /etc/puppet/services/test/manifests/foo.pp:4 on node jobserver-01.local.cloud.uk
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong. And why is `Could not find value for 'abc'`; not `abc.com`? Any idea?? Cheers!!

---

**Update: 2**

I ended up using heira and decided to give a try to the original "array of hashes" idea and having some problem implementing:

This is what I have in heira:

```
hiera -d -c /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml nag_chk m_env=talend s_env=local
[ ... ]
DEBUG: Thu Mar 21 12:28:02 +0000 2013: Got answer for key nagi_chk, final answer
DEBUG: Thu Mar 21 12:28:02 +0000 2013: Answer after outer loop = archimedes-db-02.svc.ft.com:1521 ftftp01-uvln-uk-p:22 www.google.com:80 ftaps01-lvpr-uk-local:8080
archimedes-db-02:1521 ftftp01-uvln-uk-p:22 google.com:80
```

Then, in my foo.pp

```
class test::foo {

    define bar2 () {
        $var1 = $name['addr']
        $var2 = $name['port']
        notify {"*** ${var1}_${var2} *********": }
    }
}
```

and my node.pp:

```
$array_chk = hiera('nag_chk')
$urls = inline_template("<%= '$array_chk'.split(' ').map{|kv| v1,v2 = kv.split(':'); {'addr' => v1, 'port' => v2}} -%>")
test::foo::bar2 {$urls:}
```

and as usual, I get an error:

> err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
>   SERVER: name is not an hash or array when accessing it with 0 at
>   /etc/puppet/services/talend/talend/manifests/foo.pp:10 on node
>   talend-jobserver-01.local.cloud.ft.com warning: Not using cache on
>   failed catalog err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

What's am I doing wrong? As far as I can see, the "array of hash" in right format in the `irb` console:

```
irb(main):001:0> STRING = "archimedes-db-02:1521 ftftp01-uvln-uk-p:22 google.com:80"
=> "archimedes-db-02:1521 ftftp01-uvln-uk-p:22 google.com:80"
irb(main):003:0>
irb(main):002:0> STRING.split(' ').map{|kv| v1,v2 = kv.split(':'); {'addr' => v1, 'port' => v2}}
=> [{"addr"=>"archimedes-db-02", "port"=>"1521"}, {"addr"=>"ftftp01-uvln-uk-p", "port"=>"22"}, {"addr"=>"google.com", "port"=>"80"}]
```

any further thought(s)? Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example may help solve your particular case.

```
  $foo = [{"addr" => "bar", "port" => "1"},                                     
          {"addr" => "bat", "port" => "2"}]                                     
  testmod::bar {$foo:}                                                          
  define testmod::bar () {                                                      
    $var1 = $name["addr"]                                                       
    $var2 = $name["port"]                                                       
    notify {"${var1}_${var2}": }                                                
  }
```

Put the nagios type inside the define type. You may have to change the csv to a hash.

UPDATE: Added after @MacUsers update. The following works for me :

```
  $foo = ["abc.com:80","xyz.co.uk:1512"]
  testmod::bar {$foo:}
  define testmod::bar () {
    $var1 = inline_template("<%= '$name'.split(':').first.to_s.chomp %>")
    $var2 = inline_template("<%= '$name'.split(':').last.to_s.chomp %>")
    notify {"${var1}_${var2}": }
  }
```

Running puppet agent gives me this :

```
Notice:     /Stage[main]/Testmodule/Testmodule::Testmod::Bar[abc.com:80]/Notify[abc.com_80]/message: defined 'message' as 'abc.com_80'
Notice: xyz.co.uk_1512
Notice:    /Stage[main]/Testmodule/Testmodule::Testmod::Bar[xyz.co.uk:1512]/Notify[xyz.co.uk_1512]/message: defined 'message' as 'xyz.co.uk_1512'
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I'll give a try tonight and report back. Cheers!!

Comment: just wondering, is gonna make it easier if I use Ruby DSL instead of Puppet DSL, in this case? Cheers!!

Comment: I haven't used Ruby-DSL that much, so can't comment much. You could create a hash using Ruby-DSL and then pass it to Puppet define type... Give it a try anyway :)

Comment: Tried to follow your suggestion but getting error. Details in the `Update' in the original post. Cheers!!

Comment: See updates in my answer. I would still suggest that you use a hash rather than splitting the string in an array. It will be easier if you have more than two elements in the $foo.

Comment: thanks iamauser! that works! What's the easiest way turning the returned string (e.g. `'abc.com:80,xyz.co.uk:1512'`) into a hash of array? Still don't find things are very easy in Ruby with my limited knowledge. Cheers!!

Comment: Just figured it out how to create the hash from a comma separated list of addr:port pair: `STRING.split(',').map{|kv| v1,v2 = kv.split(':'); {'addr' => v1, 'port' => v2}}`

Comment: Although it wasn't actually the answer to my question but helped me a lot to make the thing happen, so I'm accepting this answer. Thank you!